# How to add margin only on line break?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a `margin-bottom` when a string is split into multiple lines.

I read about `box-decoration-break`, but that does not seem to do what I'm trying to achieve.

The following code snippet below shows what I'm trying to do (only the last row should have a `margin-bottom`).

```css
div {
  max-width: 250px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td div {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
       <td>One</td>
       <td>1</td>
       <td>
          <div>This is a short string</div>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Two</td>
       <td>2</td>
       <td>
          <div>This is a short string</div>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Three</td>
       <td>3</td>
       <td>
          <div>This string is way too long so it will be broken</div>
       </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<div>
```

Comment: Can you share screenshot what you expect?

Comment: here is a screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/avdnJGe

Comment: You can add for above two lines add class for td or tr

Comment: What is the purpose of this margin?

Comment: Without the lines being separate block level *(at least inline-block)* Elements, you cannot do that with CSS alone. Canvas does support [.measureText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/measureText), though. Looks like you're in for a little work. Another option is to create a grid design, where one space represents one letter. Then you'll know when the text is at the end of the line.

Comment: `td div {
   line-height:40px; margin-bottom: 25px;
}`, but it also adds to the top.

Answer (score 2):

Every place I search for the answer says it's impossible, so we need a serious *witchcraft* and a little bit of limitations you have to agree to.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td span {
  display: inline-block;
}

div {
  width: 250px;
}
td span:after {
  content: "";
  margin-top: calc((100% - 250px + 1px / 10) * 16 * 10);
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
       <td>One</td>
       <td>1</td>
       <td>
         <div><span>This is a short string</span></div>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Two</td>
       <td>2</td>
       <td>
         <div><span>This is a short string</span></div>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Three</td>
       <td>3</td>
       <td>
         <div><span>This string is way too long so it will be broken</span></div>
       </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<div>
```

The best idea I've come to is to add margin based on the height, cause two and more lines makes it higher. Unfortunately percentages for heights, margins, padding, borders and probably everything else is based on parent's ... width.

So let's work with what we've got. Wrapped text means that the width reaches its maximum - let's say `250px`. One line means the width must be less than `250px`. So let's subtract max `250px` from whatever width we have. We will end up with either negative number or 0 if it reaches max width. Now let's add `1px` and multiply it by current `font-size` (`16px`). Now keep in mind that for extreme edge case where the text ends up having `249.5px` we will have half of the margin below :(. To mitigate this we can reduce `1px` `n` times and multiply it `n` times back with our `font-size`. The smaller the value, the safer it gets.

**Limitations:**

- The width of the container must be known (fixed) because you have to subtract if from `100%`.
- Font size or height of the margin must be in "pixels" as well. To multiply our tiny bit unit based values cannot be used (`1em` won't work).
- We need to wrap text with additional tag so the parent's width is based on the text (`inline` or similar). You can get rid of the `div` if you make sure this column's width stays the same.

Hope it helps ;)